# Getting formula from another sheet PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm having trouble in executing my formula using PHPexcel. I'm getting my formula from another sheet which name is **Sample New Report**. Although there are no errors when I run it but for some reason after the program is executed; it returns an error saying **Undefined variable A**. Can you help me in getting my formula running?

Here's my formula code:

```
$rowCount2  = 4;
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount2, 
      "=SUMIF('Sample New Report'!$A:$A,Incentive!$A4,'Sample New Report'!$Z:$Z)");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't anything to do with other sheets: PHPExcel does not support formulae using row (`2:2`) or column (`A:A`) references, whether in the same worksheet or in another worksheet. Use ranges instead

```
=SUMIF('Sample New Report'!$A1:$A1024,Incentive!$A4,'Sample New Report'!$Z1:$Z1024)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me! :) I'm just learning PHPExcel and didnt know all the limitations for it.